# WIX in VS 2012 Menu and Commands missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix

I just installed WIX 3.10 and I'm using VS 2012 Ultimate. I have then successfully added a WIX setup project to my solution but that's about as far as I can go because the WIX menu is not showing up. The commands buttons that should appear at the top of the solution explorer window does not appear, neither does the shortcut button that appears just below the 'clean' button when you right click the project. I have tried uninstalling and restarting my PC several times but still the same.
[snap shot of the solution explorer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut7mB.png).
I'm obviously missing something, but what? Thanks very much.

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting. This looks pretty normal to me...

Comment: Thanks jessehouwing, but I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tZVFO0IwIM and tried to following it step by step

Comment: That uses Wix Designer, a commercial product: https://www.add-in-express.com/wix-designer/index.php

Comment: Oh ok. Got it. The Wix installer I installed is really of no use then. Thanks jessehouwing

Comment: It is, but you need to do more things manually. One can actually build pretty good installers with just a few snippets of xml.

Answer (score 4):

The designer you're looking for is from a 3rd party commercial product:

- https://www.add-in-express.com/wix-designer/index.php

Normally one would write most Wix files by hand. It's relatively simple XML and the documentation isn't bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the extension: Tools -> Extensions and Updates

Then in the search box type 'wix' and Enter.

The extension name is 'Designer for Visual Studio Wix Setup Projects':

[image]